# Crossing border from Spain to Morocco - possible problems?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, spain, borders, morocco

We want to visit Spain in September 2015. Since we will visit Gibraltar too, we are thinking about going to Ceuta. Since Ceuta is very close to Morocco it would be worth to visit it for example for one or two days. We have two options:

1. Go to Ceuta by a ferry and then cross to Morocco by walking.
2. Go straight to Morocco by ferry. For example from Tariffa to Tanger Ville.

Are there some possible problems at borders to Morocco?

I think of bureaucracy (hours/days on border) or immigrants (no offence, just carefulness) and stuff.

And is it better to go straight to Tanger Ville by ferry?

Comment: I don't have many info -- hence a comment: I would expect long queues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In December 2014, I took a ferry from Spain to Tanger and, a few days later, crossed into Ceuta, after which, again a few days later, I crossed back into Morocco.

Getting into Morocco, from Spain, was a breeze. Immigration was done on the ferry.

Getting into Ceuta was a bit more cumbersome, but not a huge hassle. I waited in line for perhaps 20 minutes.
Getting back from Ceuta into Morocco was easy as well.

On the whole, all crossings were fairly straightforward, and I never felt even remotely unsafe.

I traveled on a Dutch passport.